# Vertical cell alignment with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm creating an admin page that queries then reports on the page weights of key pages for a site (landing, etc.)

As Bootstrap 4 is close, I have used it to create a layout, which I'm happy with. However for each row, the text in a cell is not vertically aligned. I can do a simple right alignment with:

```
.cell { text-align: right; }
```

but I want to vertically align as well. I believe that Bootstrap 4 is using flexbox. Is there some way to do vertical text alignment in a cell using flex? My example is here on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/timburgess/pen/KzoyQy/?editors=1100)

Comment: It seems you've added the solution to your CodePen sample which confused the hell out of me for a few minutes.

Comment: No need to apologize, I just thought I add a comment in case someone else looks at this and wonders what you mean by vertical align when everything is already vertically aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are already aligned , it's padding inside button that's making text non-aligned on second column w.r.t. first.

add follwing css to second column text :

```
padding: .375rem 0;
font-size: 1rem;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.5;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Awesome. Thankyou!

Comment: @timbo np, i would like to help you next time again

Comment: @timbo: All you need is the padding. I don't see why any of the other stuff would be necessary. font-size, font-weight and line-height already have those same values and vertical-align is not needed since the padding is doing the centering.